# addnode + v2transport (BIP324) argument available to the bitcoin.conf?

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers, bip324-p2p-encryption

I'm trying to use the new **`v2transport`** argument on `addnode=` in `bitcoin.conf` to attempt to connect to the peer using BIP324 v2 transport protocol.

I tried using, for example, the `bitcoin-cli addnode "192.168.1.94:8333" "add" true` command, and it worked.

[image]

[image]

```
bitcoind[935]: 2023-12-14T12:28:33Z New manual v2 peer connected: version: 70016, blocks=2542818, peer=7
```

Now, I want to use it by adding it to the `bitcoin.conf` file to get persistent configuration and always exec this at startup, but any combination that I try, works for me, the connection with the peer always fails.

Someone knows if this feature was added with v26.0 or not and if yes, what nomenclature I should use to get this?

Refs:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/28331

https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/26.0/

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-26.0.md#updated-rpcs

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/26.0.0/rpc/network/addnode/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to specify the v2transport option for the `-addnode` startup option.

Comment: Note that there is a PR open to make all manual (addnode/connect) connections attempt v2: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/29058 implicitly. If that lands, in 27.0 you won't need to specify anything.

Comment: Does it mean that with `v2transport=1` in `bitcoin.conf` it will not be necessary to specify any `v2transport` arguments for each pair added with `addnode=` in `bitcoin.conf` since it will always attempt the negotiation using **P2P v2** first of all?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @2F4kT0r If that PR makes it into 27.0, then yes, with 27.0 (expected release around April 2024) you will not need to specify.

Comment: Merged! https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/29239 + https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/29058

Thanks!